# 2-level cache implementation in Java

Tags: java, caching

I'm working on 2-level cache implementation in Java for the studying purpose. 
I have 2 levels: RAM is first and FS is second. 
I chose LRU strategy for my implementation and "write-back" policy between 2 levels. 
Could you please clarify:

Is it possible to make objects stored in 2nd level (file system) up-to-date in case when object changes its internal state? Is it normal practise for 2-level cache?

How can I write my object (serialize) to file in binary form if all that I know about object is that the object is Object type? Is it possible or I have to make requirment that Object should implement Serializable?

EDIT:

Actually the question about internal state is - how can I impelment it?

Comment: You can use reflection to serialize your object if you don't want to use `Serializable`.

Comment: "Actually the question is about..." the hell it is. The question, before your edit, was about two-three things, and you asked **whether** (not *how*) it's possible to update the cache when an object changes. Don't move the goalposts on existing questions - you should make every question about a single problem and make that as clear as possible.

Comment: Anyway, for the purposes of an exercise, the requirement to have objects be explicitly `Serializable` - for the purposes of the FS cache); and "cacheable" - emit notifications or set a dirty flag when their internal state changes so a write-back can occur. Java is not an operating system kernel, it doesn't seem appropriate to try and shoehorn lower-level techniques into it. (Where a regular operating system can obviously trace any write to memory.)

Comment: Also, you said that your cache is a write-back cache - doesn't this contradict updating the second-level cache when the object changes? As far as I understand, "write-back" means the second-level cache is updated when an object is evicted from the first-level cache. If you updated the second-level cache when the object changes, it'd be a write-through cache. (Also technically it seems that your second-level cache is actually the backing store but I'm not sure, it's just that you don't mention anything else that could be the backing store.)

Comment: @peter, sorry for inappropriate editing. I will consider your remark for the future. Thank you for the answer, I got your idea and it sounds good. :)

Comment: @peter, initially I didn't think about problem of "up-to-date" for 2nd level and the idea was just to use write-back cache policy. But then I found the problem of "up-to-date" and the solution really looks like "write-through".

Comment: Damn, I meant "@millimoose", not peter, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can say its a normal practice to have a 2nd level cache in your application at least i can say it on the basis of my experience. For more you can refer java specs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html).

We also implemented the 2nd level cache in our application to enhance the performance in all the database read operations. To achieve that we used the [Ehcache API](http://ehcache.org/documentation) and we found it very easier to integrate with Spring in our application as it was running on Spring framework.